# Loop through Dataframe column of URLs and parse out html tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This shouldn't be too hard, although I can't figure it, i'm betting i'm making a dumb mistake.

Here's the code that works on an individual link and returns the zestimate (the req_headers variable prevents throwing a captcha):

```
req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1404-Clearwing-Cir-Georgetown-TX-78626/121721750_zpid/'
test_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, headers=req_headers).content, 'html.parser')
results = test_soup.select_one('h4:contains("Home value")').find_next('p').get_text(strip=True)
print(results)
```

Here's the code i'm trying to get to work and return the zestimate for each link and add to a new dataframe column, but I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'` (Also, imagine i have a dataframe column of different zillow house links):

```
req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

for link in df['links']:
    test_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, headers=req_headers).content, 'html.parser')
    results = test_soup.select_one('h4:contains("Home value")').find_next('p').get_text(strip=True)
    df['zestimate'] = results
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the links sent to BS are valid? Try `for link in df['links']: print(link)` and see if these are the links you need.

Comment: @JackFleeting yep, good idea but it is printing out the links from within the dataframe, and those links are valid. you can click them from within jupyter and they work.

Comment: In that case, it probably means that (at least) one of the urls' soup doesn't have a `'h4:contains("Home value")`. If you remove that url from the df, the loop should work (until it runs into the next url without that tag).

Comment: From your error looks like the results = test_soup.select_one('h4:contains("Home value")') is returning None type. So first check if results exists, if so then go for the next operation `results = test_soup.select_one('h4:contains("Home value")') if results:   p_tag = results.find_next('p')   if p_tag:   value=get_text(strip=True) `and then add the value to the dataframe column

Answer (score 0):

I had a space before and after the links in my dataframe column :/. That was it. The code works fine. just an oversight on my part. Thanks all